# Laravel 6.x password reset activity log

Tags: laravel

### Laravel 6.x
Php 7.4.x

I am keen to store user activity in the DB. I am already able to log logins and logouts. This question is about how to log password reset requests and successful password reset attempts. I know that I need to add a function to the `App/HTTP/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php` but do not know exactly what to write there.  Please can you help?

Comment: there is an event fired when the password is reset `Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset`

Comment: thanks a lot. can you add a little snippet to an answer? and I will be marking it as answered.